# Frustum culling rectangles problem

Tags: opengl, rectangles, culling, frustum

I am trying to implement frustum culling in my OpenGL 2d game. The only kind of geometric objects in my game at this point are rectangles, so I thought this would be pretty easy, but I am getting unexpected results. I have setup a symmetrical perspective projection with a field-of-view angle of 45 degrees, and near and far planes at 0.01 and 50 respectively. The eye vector is always parallel to the z-axis, the camera can only move along the x and y axes.

My idea was to get the rectangular area of the world space that is currently visible to the camera at the z-coordinate of the rectangle I am trying to cull. Because the camera is looking at the center of the frustum, I calculate the distance to the edges of this visible rectangular area as follows:

```
GLfloat maxDistance = givenRectangle.z * tanf(0.5 * (fovAngle * M_PI/180) );
```

Then I add and substract this distance to and from the x and y coordinates of the camera to get the maximum and minimum visible x and y, and then test the given rectangle to see if it's in between these values.

My question is whether I am on the right track here, and why the above formula returns an absurdly small value (something*10^-37) when I have an object at z=5, which should clearly be visible with the Camera at (0,0,0)?

Comment: Yeah well technically I only have 2d rectangles in a 3d perspective so, whatever you'd like to call that :) The reason I want the perspective projection is that I want to be able to zoom in and out, I have a world with a topdown camera orientation

Comment: could you explain me that part please : Then I add and substract this distance to and from the x and y coordinates of the camera to get the maximum and minimum visible x and y, and then test the given rectangle to see if it's in between these values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the problem from the top, I've checked your formula - see sketch to confirm I've understood you correctly.

[image]

Given that we know A and Z and want to solve for X, I first wrote:

tan(A) = X/Z

rearranging, I get:

X = Z tan(A)

Since Z = 5 and A = 22.5 degrees...

X = 5* tan(22.5 degrees)

X = 2.07106781

So, it does seem as though you've got the maths right but your code wrong - maybe your tan function is expecting degrees rather than radians, or **fovAngle** hasn't been set?  I think you need to debug and hand-check each value.

---

Going back to the wider problem of figuring out what does and does not lie inside your frustum, you might find that you can use a different test to answer the same question more elegantly.  Many graphics coders use a "side-of-plane" test.  Consider that your viewing frustum is a volume of space bounded by a set of 6 planes (4 for the sides of your viewport, a near clipping plane and a far clipping plane).

Given a point on a plane and a normal for the plane, you can quite easily calculate the equation of a plane, which in turn [makes it trivial to test whether a given point is "inside" (in the direction of the normal) a given plane](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/planeeq/).  Iterate through all 6 planes and you'll quickly rule a given point in or out of your viewing volume.

The really neat thing about this test is how easily you can re-use it: any simple convex polygon you happen to want to do tests on (e.g. a rectangle) can be described as a set of planes, allowing you to re-use your "insider or outside" test.  Very general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is indeed what I meant. I also found out what the problem was: it was something with a double pointer to fovAngle that wasn't working properly in my specific code...One question about your way of frustum culling: am I right in suspecting that this more general approach is slower for simple rectangles than the method I described?

Comment: Glad you found the bug, sounds like a frustrating one.  Yes, the planes method is sure to be slower.  It could save you in development effort at some stage, but with your particular situation it might be overkill.

Comment: Speaking of speed, if you are writing a 2D game anyhow and really want to go all-out for performance, consider not using perspective.  If you use an orthographic projection instead, your test for "is rectangle inside screen" will be simpler again, 0 < x < screen_width.

Comment: If you wan to be able to zoom out of the scene and see if object are visible or not you need this technique, even in 2d !